# New To Android Development: App Runs On My MacBook Pro But Fails With Kotlin Typecast Exception on iMac

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-button

This is the weirdest thing..  A few weeks ago I ran into this issue and found the solution to be to update the Gradle Runtime, which I did on both computers. I decided I wanted to sit at my desk with my iMac and work last night, but could not get the app to run do to a Kotlin Typecast Exception. I switched to the remote branch I have pulled on my MacBook, but got this error:

```
09-23 12:28:29.112 4141-4141/com.example.pmarl.peedeehealthadvisor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pmarl.peedeehealthadvisor, PID: 4141
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pmarl.peedeehealthadvisor/com.example.pmarl.peedeehealthadvisor.MainActivity}: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.Button
        at com.example.pmarl.peedeehealthadvisor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I panic'd and tested the MacBook again, but it worked fine.

`

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button MyHealthData;
    private Button  MyHealthResources;
    private boolean firstStart;

    @Override
    protected void  onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*First time open code*/
        SharedPreferences app_preferences = getApplicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

        firstStart = app_preferences.getBoolean("first_time_start",true);

        /*If statement to see if the app has been open before or not*/
        if(firstStart)
        {

            /*If the app hasn't been opened before, it runs the following code
            * and sets firstStart to false*/
            editor.putBoolean("first_time_start",false);
            editor.commit();

            //do your one time code here
            launchFirstTimeLogIn();
            //Toast.makeText(this,"This is first app run!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {
            //app open directly
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




        this.MyHealthData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyHealthData);

        this.MyHealthData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                launchMyHealthData();
            }
        });

        this.MyHealthResources = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HealthResources);



        this.MyHealthResources.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                launchSearchServiceActivity();
            }
        });

    }


    private void launchMyHealthData()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, MyHealthDataActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }

    private void launchSearchServiceActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, SearchServiceActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }

    private void launchFirstTimeLogIn()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstTimeLogin.class);
        intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

`

Both are the same Gradle versions, and the same version of Android Studio. I"m not sure what this would be caused by? My logic says that if it is the Button causing the issue, like the posts I found say, it wouldn't work on my MacBook.

Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: Code, XML, full stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added it though. Also I may want to add that another student on the project made it as Kotlin back in June, but we are using Java now, which is weird given the MainActivity.kt is referenced in the error. We converted MainActivity to Java

Comment: Show the code then.

Comment: This error does not come from your OS, Android Studio or Gradle. The view in the xml cannot be found

Comment: I added it, sorry I've been trying to fix the formatting since lol. @cricket_007 my question is why does it work fine on my MacBook, but not my iMac? Code is exactly the same. That blows my mind

Comment: Well, as you pointed out, the MainActivity should be Java, so I suspect the issue is that you pulled a different remote branch than you expect

Answer (score 0):

> null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.Button

I'm assuming that you declared a `Button` like this: (*for example*)

```
mineBtn = findViewById(R.id.yourbtnid) as Button
```

Add "`?`" after the `as`:

```
mineBtn = findViewById(R.id.yourbtnid) as? Button
```

Then error should be gone.

---

**Edit:** Remove `this.` before declaring widgets. And declare a widget like this:

```
MyHealthData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyHealthData);
```

<sub>Note that it's better to change `R.id.MyHealthData` from xml layout to be make sure it won't cause other issues in future.</sub>

Comment: After looking at the code I believe its the (Button) casting that my classmate did. When i go to change it to a similar line as above, it won't recognize "as" or "Button"? Are they instantiated as classes or variables?

Comment: I assumed that you are using `kotlin`. I just saw your codes (Seems like you converted it to java). Remove `this.` before declaring `Button` or methods when you're using those codes inside `onCreate()`. Also, make sure about this id from your xml: `R.id.MyHealthData` & `R.id.HealthResources` and check if it is declared as `Button`. Removing `this.` will solve the issue I hope. However, I've faced the similiar issue when were using Kotlin and my answer is for `Kotlin` since it sounds like you were using kotlin for your codes at first.

Comment: Okay... This is why I am so confused. I just deleted the `.this` and the `(Button)` and ran it and it failed with same issue. Then I added them back and its working... The code is exactly the same as it was when I made this post. It is also the same on my MacBook and no issues.  I am using virtual Pixel 2 XL, but it also wouldn't work with my Pixel 2, S9,and S5 test devices.

Comment: `this.` is not necessary in your case. Don't delete `(Button)` also. Anyways, you better to rename `MyHealthData` (`R.id.MyHealthData`) from the xml. Perhaps that will cause some other issues in future. However, it should work fine now if you don't use kotlin to see the same error which I've gave the solution for that.

Comment: Do you know why it would be working on 50% of development environments that are identical with the same code?  Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: You're actually confusing yourself I suppose. I've had the same issue with the `Kotlin` which I'm already facing it too. The problem might be the added `Kotlin` to the Android Studio since If you checked, the developers are releasing new updates repeatedly one after another to be more compatible with the Android Studio. But if you use those codes in java (Just like I said, without `this.` and without removing `(Button)`) It will work on both of your devices.